Flickering half white login screen and then nothing (Debian)
I've recently installed Debian on a fresh system with a new SSD but it has stopped being usable, now I can only reach the login screen which is 50% white. The screen flickers to fully white when I move the mouse and on login the screen goes fully black (no signal to the monitor). I can access the terminal otherwise have no control.
I am using an old Radeon card- an RX 460- but also have a Nvidia GTX 970 in there.
